# How do you write “ㅉ” naturally?

Tags: handwriting

I know that “ㅈ” is written differently [from the keyboard] naturally.
Is “ㅉ” the same as the keyboard-written way or is it written differently naturally?

Comment: It is just ㅈ times two. It looks like スス with almost no space between the two スs. Usually the lower left stroke of the right one goes below the lower right stroke of the left one. You can see an example by googling "진짬뽕".

Comment: What do you mean by "written differently from the keyboard"? Have you searched for handwritten pictures of the character online to see what it looks like?

Answer (score 2):

This is how people write `ㅉ`. (I found these images from Google.)

There isn't really any other way AFAIK or at least I haven't seen it.

[image: ㅉ]
[image: ㅉ]

Comment: To clarify: the right image (four strokes) is how people write ㅉ. The left side is not technically wrong, but I think it's very uncommon in handwriting, sort of like how nobody writes "printed style" g (= the g in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Times_New_Roman ).